# Kotlin saving video to gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, video, gallery

I tried saving video to gallery like i found on example:

```
private fun saveVideoToInternalStorage3(filePath: String) {
  val newfile: File
  try {
     val currentFile = File(filePath)
     val fileName = currentFile.name
     val cw = ContextWrapper(applicationContext)
     val directory = cw.getDir("videoDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
     newfile = File(directory.absolutePath, fileName)
     if(currentFile.exists()) {
        val `in`: InputStream = FileInputStream(currentFile)
        val out: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(newfile)

        // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
        val buf = ByteArray(1024)
        var len: Int
        while(`in`.read(buf).also {len = it} > 0) {
           out.write(buf, 0, len)
        }
        scanner(filePath)
        `in`.close()
        out.close()
        Log.d("", "Video file saved successfully.")
        Toast.makeText(this, "Push Video Saved TO Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
     } else {
        Log.d("", "Video saving failed. Source file missing.")
     }
  } catch(e: java.lang.Exception) {
     Log.d("", "EXS " + e.message)
     e.printStackTrace()
  }
```

And it works fine it shows message "Video file saved successfully." But there is no video in my gallery.

After searching for problem i found post that says you need a scanner and i tried:

```
 private fun scanner(path: String) {
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, arrayOf(path), null, object: OnScanCompletedListener {
     override fun onScanCompleted(path: String, uri: Uri?) {
        Log.i("", "Finished scanning $path")
     }
  })
```

But still no luck. Does any1 know what is going on? Saving images in gallery works fine btw.